# Integer to bitfield as a list

Tags: python, list, bit-fields

I've created a method to convert an `int` to a bitfield (in a list) and it works, but I'm sure there is more elegant solution- I've just been staring at it for to long.

I'm curious, how would you convert a `int` to a bitfield represented in a `list`?

```
def get(self):
    results = []

    results.append(1 if (self.bits &   1) else 0)
    results.append(1 if (self.bits &   2) else 0)
    results.append(1 if (self.bits &   4) else 0)
    results.append(1 if (self.bits &   8) else 0)
    results.append(1 if (self.bits &  16) else 0)
    results.append(1 if (self.bits &  32) else 0)
    results.append(1 if (self.bits &  64) else 0)
    results.append(1 if (self.bits & 128) else 0)

    return results

def set(self, pin, direction):
    pin -= 1
    if pin not in range(0, 8): raise ValueError

    if direction: self.bits |= (2 ** pin)
    else: self.bits &=~(2 ** pin)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

How about this:

```
def bitfield(n):
    return [int(digit) for digit in bin(n)[2:]] # [2:] to chop off the "0b" part
```

This gives you

```
>>> bitfield(123)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
>>> bitfield(255)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> bitfield(1234567)
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

This only works for positive integers, though.

**EDIT:**

Conversion to `int` using `int()` is a bit overkill here. This is a lot faster:

```
def bitfield(n):
    return [1 if digit=='1' else 0 for digit in bin(n)[2:]]
```

See the timings:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("[int(digit) for digit in bin(123)[2:]]")
7.895014818543946
>>> timeit.timeit("[123 >> i & 1 for i in range(7,-1,-1)]")
2.966295244250407
>>> timeit.timeit("[1 if digit=='1' else 0 for digit in bin(123)[2:]]")
1.7918431924733795
```

Comment: `[123 >> i & 1 for i in range(7,-1,-1)]` is the fastest on my machine.

Comment: @tMC: I've redone the timings on both my PCs (Win 7 Ultimate 64bit), under Python 2.7.3 and 3.2.3, and my solution was always faster by at least 20 % (Python 2) and 45 % (Python 3).

Comment: the difference is negligible.  I just thought it was interesting that i got different results on my Linux laptop.

Comment: This is reversing the correct order of the bitfields because it's reading the chars of the string from left to right. e.g. `bitfield(8) = [1, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: Huh, right. Nobody noticed that for over ten years :) - well, if the reverse order is desired, it's easy to reverse the list afterwards (`...[::-1]`)

Comment: Bad answer. `bin()` converts to a string which is always going to be slower than using integers and bit shifts.

Answer (score 30):

This doesn't use `bin`:

```
 b = [n >> i & 1 for i in range(7,-1,-1)]
```

and this is how to handle any integer this way:

```
 b = [n >> i & 1 for i in range(n.bit_length() - 1,-1,-1)]
```

See [`bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length).

If you want index 0 of the list to correspond to the lsb of the int, change the range order, i.e.

```
b = [n >> i & 1 for i in range(0, n.bit_length()-1)]
```

Note also that using n.bit_length() can be a point of failure if you're trying to represent fixed length binary values. It returns the minimum number of bits to represent n.

Comment: This is perfect- I knew there was a list comprehension I was missing

Comment: It may handle any integers in this way:

[n >> i & 1 for i in range(n.bit_length() - 1,-1,-1)]

Comment: @mennanov: thanks, added (btw, feel free to edit posts if you have something valuable to add).

Comment: For the sake of performance, you should use `%2` instead of `&1`, even though the latter looks smarter: `timeit.timeit("n=193; n%2")` returns `0.043587817999650724`, while `timeit.timeit("n=193; n&1")` returns `0.0545583209986944` (I set `n` to an arbitrary value so as to avoid optimizations).

Comment: The last example should be `range(0, n.bit_length())` as range stop value is not inclusive.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
>>>n=1794
>>>bitfield=list(bin(n))[2:]
>>>bitfield
['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0']
```

This does not work for negative n though and as you see gives you a list of strings

Comment: +1, I seem to forget that there is `list()` constructor all the time.

Comment: Even though it does not return list of integers.

Comment: This is not what tMC asked for. He needs a list of integers, you give him a list of strings. As nice as the `list()` constructor may be, it's not the right tool here.

Comment: `map(lambda b: int(b), bitfield)`

Comment: @Kroltan map(int, bitfield)

Answer (score 3):

### Array with fixed length

Array with fixed length:

```
>>> '{0:07b}'.format(12)
'0001100'
```

Do you believe string is also an array? No? See:

```
>>> [int(x) for x in '{0:07b}'.format(12)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Does not work for negative values

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> [int(x) for x in np.binary_repr(123)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this for my program where you specify a template to get your values from an int:

```
def field(template, value):
    sums = [int(v) if v.__class__==str else len(bin(v))-2 for v in template]
    return [(value>> (sum(sums[:i]) if i else 0) )&(~(~0<<int(t)) if t.__class__==str else t) for i,t in enumerate(template)]
```

**how to use**
in the template, specify ints relating to your bit-sizes:

```
field([0b1,0b111,0b1111], 204) #>>> [0, 6, 12]
```

or you can specify the bit-size of each value needed using strings: (noob friendly)

```
field(['1','3','4'], 204) #>>> [0, 6, 12]
```

EDIT: and vice versa: (separate code)

```
field(['1','3','4'], [0, 6, 12]) #>>> 204
field([0b1,0b111,0b1111], [0,3,9]) #>>> 150
```

the code:

```
def field(template, value):
    res = 0
    for t, v in zip(template, value)[::-1]: res = (res << (t.bit_length() if t.__class__ is int else int(t)) )|v
    return res
```

EDIT2: faster code^