# Is there a way to convert mp4/wav files to a byte array in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

Working on trying to write mp4 and wav files to byte arrays, so that I am able to share them with other apps. Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I assume if you're using `python` then its same as reading `text_file` or `video_file`.

Let's assume if your filename is `test.ts` then you can use below function.

```py
def get_bytes_from_file(filename):  
    return open(filename, "rb").read()  

get_bytes_from_file("test.ts")
```

You can also use scipy inbuild function `scipy.io.wavfile.read` and/or `scipy.io.wavfile.write`.[Refer this.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html)

If you have decimal value that you would like to convert to binary you can use the following:

```py
In [3]: import numpy as np 
   ...:  
   ...: def bitfield(n): 
   ...:     """Convert integer into bitfield (as list) 
   ...:     From StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10322018/ 
   ...:     """ 
   ...:     return [int(digit) for digit in bin(n)[2:]]  
   ...:                                                                         

In [4]: p = 0x91 
   ...: p = np.array(bitfield(p))                                               

In [5]: p                                                                       
Out[5]: array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

If you want to convert string message to binary you can use this:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
        import codecs

In[2]: s = '44.6488N,63.5752W,20.5,2.25,125.6,11.5,6.8,T10.5,271.4,35.5,44.6491N,63.5755W'.encode('utf-8')

In[4]: s.hex()
Out[4]: '34342e363438384e2c36332e35373532572c32302e352c322e32352c3132352e362c31312e352c362e382c5431302e352c3237312e342c33352e352c34342e363439314e2c36332e3537353557'


In[10]: print(codecs.decode("34342e363438384e2c36332e35373532572c32302e352c322e32352c3132352e362c31312e352c362e382c5431302e352c3237312e342c33352e352c34342e363439314e2c36332e3537353557", "hex").decode('utf-8'))
Out[10]: 44.6488N,63.5752W,20.5,2.25,125.6,11.5,6.8,T10.5,271.4,35.5,44.6491N,63.5755W

In[11]: hex_string = "34342e363438384e2c36332e35373532572c32302e352c322e32352c3132352e362c31312e352c362e382c5431302e352c3237312e342c33352e352c34342e363439314e2c36332e3537353557"
    for i in range(len(hex_string)//2):
        print('{0}'.format(hex_string[i*2:i*2+2]), end=":")
Out[11]: 34:34:2e:36:34:38:38:4e:2c:36:33:2e:35:37:35:32:57:2c:32:30:2e:35:2c:32:2e:32:35:2c:31:32:35:2e:36:2c:31:31:2e:35:2c:36:2e:38:2c:54:31:30:2e:35:2c:32:37:31:2e:34:2c:33:35:2e:35:2c:34:34:2e:36:34:39:31:4e:2c:36:33:2e:35:37:35:35:57:        


In[12]: p = '34342e363438384e2c36332e35373532572c32302e352c322e32352c3132352e362c31312e352c362e382c5431302e352c3237312e342c33352e352c34342e363439314e2c36332e3537353557'
    p = int(p, 16)
    p = np.array(bitfield(p))
    p
Out[12] : array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
           0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
           1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
           1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
           0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
           1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
           1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
           0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
           0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
           1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
           0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
           1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
           0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
           1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
           1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
           0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
           0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
           1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
           1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
           0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```