# Python: How to get all possible bin combinations from a set of data with a weight limit?

Tags: python, bin-packing

I have a list of numbers which all correspond to items of different weight:

```
weights = [50, 40, 30, 100, 150, 12, 150, 10, 5, 4]
```

I need to split the values into two bins with the caveat that the bin sum total cannot exceed 300.

e.g. The simplest one I can think of is:

```
bin1 = [150, 150] = 300
bin2 = [50, 40, 30, 100, 12, 10, 5, 4] = 251
```

I want to be able to get all the combinations of these weights that would satisfy this caveat, unsure how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is brute-forcing it by binning all possible permutations of the list

there has to be a better (more clever) way of doing that - it's terribly slow. (but I'm supposed to be doing other things right now ;-))

```
from itertools import permutations

max_bin_size = 300
weights = [50, 40, 30, 100, 150, 12, 150, 10, 5, 4]

bin_combinations = set()

def to_bins(weights):
    bin = []
    for weight in weights:
        if weight > max_bin_size:
            raise ValueError("wtf?")
        if sum(bin) + weight > max_bin_size:
            yield tuple(sorted(bin))
            bin = [weight]
        else:
            bin.append(weight)
    yield tuple(sorted(bin))


for permutation in set(permutations(weights)):
    bin_combinations.add(tuple(sorted(to_bins(permutation))))

for combination in bin_combinations:
    print(combination)

# ((4, 10, 40, 100), (5, 12, 150), (30, 50, 150))
# ((4, 5, 10, 40, 50, 100), (12, 30), (150, 150))
# ((4, 10, 30, 150), (5, 50, 100), (12, 40, 150))
# ((4, 5, 30, 100), (10, 50, 150), (12, 40, 150))
# ((4, 12, 50, 100), (5, 10, 30, 40), (150, 150))
# ((4, 5, 150), (10, 30, 40, 150), (12, 50, 100))
# ...
```

## Update:

a version with reuse of bins (assuming one can put the weights freely into any available bin):

```
from itertools import permutations

max_bin_size = 300
weights = [50, 40, 30, 100, 150, 12, 150, 10, 5, 4]

bin_combinations = set()


def to_bins(weights):
    bins = [[]]
    for weight in weights:
        if weight > max_bin_size:
            raise ValueError("wtf?")
        for bin in bins:
            if sum(bin) + weight > max_bin_size:
                continue
            bin.append(weight)
            break
        else:
            bins.append([weight])            
    return tuple(sorted(tuple(sorted(bin)) for bin in bins))


for permutation in set(permutations(weights)):
    bin_combinations.add(to_bins(permutation))

print(len(bin_combinations), "combinations")
for combination in bin_combinations:
    print(combination)

# 14 combinations
# ((4, 5, 10, 12, 30, 50, 150), (40, 100, 150))
# ((4, 5, 10, 30, 40, 50, 150), (12, 100, 150))
# ((4, 12, 30, 100, 150), (5, 10, 40, 50, 150))
# ((4, 100, 150), (5, 10, 12, 30, 40, 50, 150))
# ((4, 5, 12, 30, 50, 150), (10, 40, 100, 150))
# ((4, 5, 10, 12, 100, 150), (30, 40, 50, 150))
# ((4, 5, 12, 30, 40, 50, 150), (10, 100, 150))
# ((4, 5, 40, 100, 150), (10, 12, 30, 50, 150))
# ((4, 10, 12, 30, 40, 50, 150), (5, 100, 150))
# ((4, 5, 10, 30, 100, 150), (12, 40, 50, 150))
# ((4, 5, 10, 12, 30, 40, 150), (50, 100, 150))
# ((4, 10, 40, 50, 150), (5, 12, 30, 100, 150))
# ((4, 5, 10, 12, 40, 50, 150), (30, 100, 150))
# ((4, 5, 10, 12, 30, 40, 50, 100), (150, 150))
```

Comment: This appears to generate three bins at a time when I need it to only be two, how would I get this code to generate two bins?

Comment: it generates all possible combinations, including those where only two bins are used. 

to get only those with two bins:  `for combination in (c for c in bin_combinations if len(c) == 2):`

Comment: I just posted an update, where bins can be reused.
in that case all combinations will have only two bins.

Comment: Many thanks for this, I was wondering if there was a way to pass the list index through as well, so instead of the bins printing out the weights it will show the index number instead so something like:

weights = [50, 40, 30, 100, 150, 12, 150, 10, 5, 4]
index -->  [  0,   1,   2,     3,     4,   5,     6,   7, 8, 9]
# 14 combinations
# ((4, 5, 10, 12, 30, 50, 150), (40, 100, 150)) -> ((9, 8, 7, 5, 2, 0, 4), (1, 3, 6))

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking for another approach to this problem. The solution I propose is to use masks to test the different possible combinations. A friend of mine also suggested a more complex solution but about 10 times faster, using pruning.

With both solutions, we find 33 solutions for the given example.

### Simple solution

The solution I am proposing is the following (for an explanation of the code see further):

```py
import numpy as np

def get_bins(weights, max_bin_size):
    my_bins = set()
    weights = np.array(sorted(weights))
    for i in range(1, 2 ** (len(weights) - 1)):
        mask = np.zeros(len(weights), dtype=bool)
        binary = np.fromiter((int(digit) for digit in bin(i)[2:]), dtype=bool)
        mask[len(weights) - len(binary):] = binary
        if sum(weights[mask]) <= max_bin_size and sum(weights[~mask]) <= max_bin_size:
            my_bins.add((tuple(weights[~mask]), tuple(weights[mask])))
    return my_bins
```

Results:

```py
>>> max_bin_size = 300
>>> weights = [50, 40, 30, 100, 150, 12, 150, 10, 5, 4]
>>> bins = get_bins(weights, max_bin_size)
>>> print(len(bins))
33
>>> for b in bins:
>>>     print(b, sum(b[0]), sum(b[1]))
((4, 5, 10, 12, 30, 50, 150), (40, 100, 150)) 261 290
((4, 5, 10, 30, 40, 50, 150), (12, 100, 150)) 289 262
((4, 5, 12, 30, 50, 150), (10, 40, 100, 150)) 251 300
...
```

### Optimized solution

```py
from typing import List, Tuple, Optional
from itertools import chain, repeat, starmap


# Order weights in decreasing order, then compute a list of tuple (weight, count)
def counter(list_object: List):
    result = []
    list_object.sort(reverse=True)
    current = None
    count = 0
    for elt in list_object:
        if current == elt:
            count = count + 1
        elif current is not None:
            result.append((current, count))
            count = 1
            current = elt
        else:
            current = elt
            count = 1
    if current is not None:
        result.append((current, count))
    return result


class BinPacking:
    def __init__(self, max_bin_size: int, weights: List[int]):
        self.count_weights: List[Tuple[int, int]] = counter(weights)
        self.max_bin_size: int = max_bin_size
        self.bin1: List[Optional[Tuple[int, int]]] = [None] * len(self.count_weights)
        self.bin2: List[Optional[Tuple[int, int]]] = [None] * len(self.count_weights)
        self.solutions: List[Tuple[List[int], List[int]]] = []
        self.explore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True)

    # Add a new solution, transform lists of (weight, count) into flat list of weights
    def add_solution(self, bin1_index: int, bin2_index: int):
        list1 = list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, self.bin1[:bin1_index])))
        list2 = list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, self.bin2[:bin2_index])))
        self.solutions.append((list1, list2))

    def explore(self, weight_index: int, weight1: int, weight2: int, index1: int, index2: int, same: bool):
        if weight_index >= len(self.count_weights):
            self.add_solution(index1, index2)
            return

        weight, count = self.count_weights[weight_index]
        if same:
            minimum = (count - 1) // 2
        else:
            minimum = -1
        for i in range(count, minimum, -1):
            if (weight1 + i * weight) > max_bin_size or (weight2 + (count - i) * weight) > max_bin_size:
                continue
            if i > 0:
                self.bin1[index1] = (weight, i)
                i1 = index1 + 1
            else:
                i1 = index1
            if i < count:
                self.bin2[index2] = (weight, count - i)
                i2 = index2 + 1
            else:
                i2 = index2
            same2 = same and (i == (count - i))
            self.explore(weight_index + 1, weight1 + i * weight, weight2 + (count - i) * weight, i1, i2, same2)
```

Results:

```py
>>> max_bin_size = 300
>>> weights = [50, 40, 30, 100, 150, 12, 150, 10, 5, 4]
>>> binpacking = BinPacking(max_bin_size, weights)
>>> print(len(binpacking.solutions))
33
>>> print("\n".join(str(b) for b in binpacking.solutions))
([150, 150], [100, 50, 40, 30, 12, 10, 5, 4])
([150, 100, 50], [150, 40, 30, 12, 10, 5, 4])
([150, 100, 40, 10], [150, 50, 30, 12, 5, 4])
...
```

### Simple solution explanation

Before starting, it is interesting to note that we can systematically put the first value of the `weights` in the same bin, which reduces the problem to `2^(n-1)` combinations.

To generate the mask my proposal is to iterate `i` from `1` to `2^(n-1)` and convert this integer into a binary number represented as an array ([Integer to bitfield as a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321978/integer-to-bitfield-as-a-list)).

This gives the following code:

```py
weights = np.array(weights)
for i in range(1, 2 ** (len(weights) - 1)):
    mask = np.zeros(len(weights), dtype=bool)
    binary = np.fromiter((int(digit) for digit in bin(i)[2:]), dtype=bool)
    mask[len(weights) - len(binary):] = binary
```

Now we add a condition to keep only the pairs of bins whose total weight is less than the desired maximum:

```
def get_bins(weights, max_bin_size):
    weights = np.array(weights)
    for i in range(1, 2 ** (len(weights) - 1)):
        mask = np.zeros(len(weights), dtype=bool)
        binary = np.fromiter((int(digit) for digit in bin(i)[2:]), dtype=bool)
        mask[len(weights) - len(binary):] = binary
        if sum(weights[mask]) <= max_bin_size and sum(weights[~mask]) <= max_bin_size:
            yield weights[~mask], weights[mask]
```

With this code we get `65` solutions, the cause: some redundant solutions appear if a weight value is present in several copies in the `weights`. In the example given, we have twice the value `150`, the permutations of these two values give us two solutions for each combination where the two weights `150` are in different bins. There is only 1 combination where they are in the same bin, and 32 where they are in different bins, which gives us `32*2 + 1 = 65` combinations.

To remove redundant combinations, a simple solution is to sort the list of `weights` and to use sets:

```py
def get_bins(weights, max_bin_size):
    my_bins = set() # the set
    weights = np.array(sorted(weights)) # here we are sorting the weights
    for i in range(1, 2 ** (len(weights) - 1)):
        mask = np.zeros(len(weights), dtype=bool)
        binary = np.fromiter((int(digit) for digit in bin(i)[2:]), dtype=bool)
        mask[len(weights) - len(binary):] = binary
        if sum(weights[mask]) <= max_bin_size and sum(weights[~mask]) <= max_bin_size:
            my_bins.add((tuple(weights[~mask]), tuple(weights[mask])))
    return my_bins
```

### Optimized solution explanation

The explanation of the code will come soon ... In the meantime, here are some details about optimizations:

The `counter` function is equivalent but faster than:

```py
sorted(Counter(weights).items(), reverse=True)
```

In the same idea, the code used in `add_solution` is equivalent but faster than:

```py
list1 = [elt for (x,y) in bin1[:bin1_index] for elt in [x]*y]
```

Comment: Updated with the solution using pruning given by a friend.